# How to export the data in one go in Toad for Oracle? (without first running it to display the data)

Tags: sql, oracle, export, toad

I want to export/extract the results of the query at once, without running the query first and only then after getting the result.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can write a script that will be run from the command line (Linux/Windows) and redirect the  output (using ">" sign) to a file. Still you have to know how to use SQL*PLUS...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to achieve this using Toad:

1. right click on table name
2. select "**Export Data**" from context menu
3. write "**where**" statement of your export query
4. select destination (clipboard/file)
5. click "**ok**"

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SPOOL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm) directive to output results directly to file. This will work in plain SQLPLUS also.